# Can I make Epiphany identify itself as another browser?

Tags: browser

I want to use the web browser Epiphany as a secondary browser, but Windows Live Mail won't let me log in using this web browser. For that reason, I want Epiphany to identify itself as another browser, e.g. Firefox. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, epiphany doesn't support masquarading itself as another browser. If you would like a browser with this capability, Midori is a nice lightweight web browser that supports disquising itself as other browsers. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, but for some reason, Windows Live Mail won't let me log in with Midori, using the plugin you mentioned.

Comment: Hmm... does a VM with windoze work?

Comment: Don't know, I'll check soon :-)

Comment: That is strange that you have to use Windows or Mac to use hotmail.

Comment: I've just checked, but Windows Live Mail won't let me log in with Midori on Microsoft Windows 7 either, even when using the disguise.

Comment: Hmm... this is yet another case of Microsoft being a pain. This is unfortunate, and I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: Well, nothing, really. You answered my question, which I'm thankful for.

Comment: Well, I guess your'e stuck with virtuabox for this one :).

Comment: No, I _can_ use Ubuntu's Firefox to open Windows Live Mail. It just won't work in Midori or Epiphany, not even when it's used on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Oh... that's good. At least it's openable at all.